# Spring boot: view unable to reach controller and having "400 BAD_REQUEST"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I try to do a java web application using:
SpringBoot
Mysql
JDBC
Design pattern: MVC, DAO
And Thymeleaf
And I'm trying to send a data from one of my views:

```
                    <td th:text="${Inj.sleepTest}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${Inj.sleepDose}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${Inj.nightTest}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${Inj.comment}"></td>
                    <td>
                        <form th:action="@{/delInj}" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" id="id_injection" name="id_injection" value="${Inj.id_injection}">
                            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </td>
```

to my controler:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delInj", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView delinject(Injection inj){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("userOnly/MyInjections");
        int i = inj.getId_injection();
        System.out.println(i);

        return mv;

    }
```

but i have the error "400 BAD_REQUEST - Bad Request" in my browser.
I tried with "@RequestMapping" and "PostMapping" but neither of them seams to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this sort of an issue using Java record classes.  In my case I wasn't passing all of the record fields.  Two ways to fix this. 1. Pass all the fields
2. Add a constructor to the record that defaults optional fields to a default value.  It sure would be nice if spring would enable you to turn on some response body or logging to let you know what actually was wrong with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added  @RequestBody annotation to the method.

Like,

```
public ModelAndView delinject(@RequestBody Injection inj){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("userOnly/MyInjections");
    int i = inj.getId_injection();
    System.out.println(i);

    return mv;

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it's giving me the "415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE - Unsupported Media Type" error

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/delInj", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes {"application/json"})  Try adding consumes parameter. Is this object in json format? You are getting this error because controller expects different format but you are posting different data.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Request In general  means: that the structure of your Request Body does not match the JSON sent (may be  Types, constraints, structure ...)
check the JSON you sent in the request and the expected  Request Body "Model"